# function handle jQuery event and parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Take the following code,

```
// Update button clicked
function updateEntity(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var name = $(this).attr("name");

    ...
    // some stuff
    ...
}

$(document).on("click", ".updateEntity", updateEntity);
```

Currently I have this for (go figure) updating an entity I've editted on button click. Now, its parameter is particularly expecting a jQuery event. However, I want to also be able to call this function (end goal: to minimize code) outside of a jQuery event. Like so,

```
// Do an update but then redirect to prevent adding the same estimate twice.
function createEstimate(e) {
    updateEntity(e);

    var link = $(this).attr("href");
    window.location.href = link;
}

$(document).on("click", ".createEntity", createEstimate);
```

**Question:** How would I go about calling `updateEntity` or setting the function up, so that I can supply it to the click-event handler and call it like a function and still have it used correctly? Is this goal realistic or should I be structuring this differently if I want to achieve such a goal?

(Encase it is not obvious, my current problem is that on the function call `updateEntity(e);` `$(this)` becomes `window` instead of the clicked link.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to set `this` correctly:

```
updateEntity.call(this, e);
```

[Learn more about `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: Wow, wasn't expecting the question to have that simple of an answer. Thank you.